# Why angular model interfaces are exported?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In angular - the models (model interfaces) are declared like so:

```
export interface PersonInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

and then in some other component,service etc. your import this interface and use it like so:

```
...
import { PersonInterface } from './blabla';
...
export class SomeService {
  person: PersonInterface;
}
```

---

**So my question is - what is the purpose of using `export` in the declaration of the interface?**

```
interface PersonInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

If I don't use export - I can still use it in the service and I even do not need to import it:

```
export class SomeService {
  person: PersonInterface;
}
```

Everything works fine, no errors and from the IDE I can go to the declaration if the interface (Ctrl+Click over the interface name). Am I missing something?

Cheers

Comment: it should throw the error `Cannot find name 'PersonInterface'` if the the interface is declared in a different file than the component and not exported and imported.

IDE errors will depend from IDE to IDE and the plugins used in IDE. But on `ng serve` you will be getting the above error

Comment: It shouldn't. You must have a build config that automatically imports stuff (though it's weird, never saw that). What does `ng build --prod` give you?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA - I haven't installed plugins and the IDE don't gives me errors. However - indeed I see the error - SomeService -> Cannot find name 'PersonInterface'.

Comment: Sometimes, Angular suppresses the error in dev mode. Please do a PROD build or run "ng serve --aot". It should throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes to a long story of javascript history. In early ages you had to manually specify your javascript files using `<script src="name.js">` tag with the exact order - top to bottom. After the script is attached all it's declarations like `var a = 5` or `function util(){}` will be available for all the scripts *below* it and globally. It was very hard to *hide* this declarations from the global scope to achieve encapsulation, so there became a need to create something new.

Later on the `es modules` arrived. In order to use some function from other script, you had to `export` it at the very end of that script. That means that all the other, non-exported declarations (functions and variables), were *encapsulated* (hidden) from other scripts. This led to more resilient scripts with some defense from accident modifications (imagine someone uses a bunch of scripts for the first time, it would be a nightmare to analyze 10+ scripts without any docs). The script with `export` declaration looked like:

```
var a = 5;
function b(){};

module.exports = {
  a: a,
  b: b
}
```

In 2012s the Typescript was created. Besides all it's beautiful capabilities like static types, proper type-checking and syntax sugar, it also provided a better way to `export/import` functions, variables and classes. The syntax became:

- `import Something from '../other.script'` for default exports

```
// other.script.ts contents
export default const A = '5'; // this will be imported in other file
```

- `import {exactOne, exactTwo} from '../other.script'` for non-default exports

```
// other.script.ts contents
export const exactOne = 1;
export const exactTwo = 2;
export const exactThree = 3; // this is NOT imported above, but it's possible to import this const.
const exactFour = 4; // this const cannot be imported at all
```

- `import * as AllTogether from '../other.script'` for bulk import.

```
// other.script.ts contents
export const a = 'a';
export const b = 'b';

// the AllTogether variable above will be imported like {a: 'a', b: 'b'}
```

Hope this helped!